# catch ctrl+pagedown event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keyboard-events

How do I catch a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> key-pressed event with jQuery?

I need to save the events in a buffer (and handle it later).
I tried to use this code, but don't get this events. Instead, the browser replacing its opened tabs.

```
function set_events(){
  $(".text_events").keypress(function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    e.preventDefault();
    keyboardBuffer.push(keyCode);
  });   
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking like there are some key combos that cannot be overridden. I tried getting it to work and could not. It works fine for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> which is reload but I couldn't get it to work with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. I think it is a safety mechanism built into the browser.

Comment: Hi @Logan, on a second thought, I guess you are right. Actually, I would expect a good browser to block the preventDefault of such a combination.